# ASP.NET Core EF Code First appsettings.json

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm looking for a method to switch dynamically between production and test environment.

I have two different connection strings to MSSQL databases. I want to dynamically pass this to my dbContext:

```
   services.AddDbContext<ViggrContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("TestDatabase")));
```

I have two types of publish profiles, one for Test and another for Production environment.
In this profile I choose a connection to the database. Ofcourse the Test profile points to the TestDatabase connection string and the Production profile points to the Production Database.
[image]

But how can I dynamically load the Startup.cs class in this section of the code?

```
   services.AddDbContext<ViggrContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("TestDatabase")));
```

Do you have any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3):

You can configure different environment connection strings in different appsettings files like this-

For test environment, use appsettings.**test**.json

```
 "Data": {
    "ViggrContext": {
      "ConnectionString": "" /*<<== TestDatabase connection string */
    },
```

For prod environment, use appsettings.**prod**.json

```
 "Data": {
    "ViggrContext": {
      "ConnectionString": "" /*<<== ProdDatabase connection string */
    },
```

Use **ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT** environment variable to set current environment as **Test** or **Prod** values.

In Startup, you can use like this-

```
     services.AddDbContext<ViggrContext>(options =>
options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:ViggrContext:ConnectionString"]));
```

See if this helps.